# How to check if file is empty or it has only blank characters?

Tags: shell, files

This will notify us if the file is empty:

```
[[ ! -s $file ]] && echo "hello there I am empty file !!!"
```

But how to check if a file has blank spaces (spaces or tabs)?

- empty file can include empty spaces / TAB

Comment: If the file have space characters in it, it's not empty, is it?

Comment: empty include blank spaces for my task

Comment: `cat $file | tr -s " " > $file; [ ! -s $file ] && echo "hello there I am empty file !!!"`

Comment: @Jesse_b I'm pretty sure that would truncate the file before even executing `cat`...

Comment: In that case I should be able to do just:  `tr -s " " > $file; [ ! -s $file ] && echo "hello there I am empty file !!!"` no?  Either way the command with `cat` works and doesn't without.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just `grep` for a character other than space:

```
grep -q '[^[:space:]]' < "$file" &&
  printf '%s\n' "$file contains something else than whitespace characters"
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to the other answers but using a negated `grep -q`

```
if ! grep -q '[^[:space:]]' "$file"; then
    echo "file is empty"
else
    echo "File has data"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check for empty file content within an **if condition** `[[ ... ]]`, then surround the grep with `-z $( grep ... )` (without -q):

```
if [[ -z $(grep '[^[:space:]]' $file) ]] ; then
  echo "Empty file" 
  ...
fi
```

I had to use this, in order to avoid following error when running:

```
$ [[ grep -q '[^[:space:]]' $file ]]
```

> -bash: conditional binary operator expected
>
> -bash: syntax error near `-q'

Comment: This solves an issue that user in the question does not have.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda, I've added this answer, as people might find it useful when using square brackets around the grep condition.

Comment: It's just `if grep -q '[^[:space:]]' $file`. The `[[` are *not* part of the if syntax, they are a command that returns status according to some condition. You are already checking status, so you should have just `if grep -q …`