# bash + how to verify if file is empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, files

as all know this syntax will print file is empty

```
[ -s file.name ] || echo "file is empty"
```

but what in case file is with spaces or TAB or blank spaces ? , but without any real character as a-z 1-9 and so on

so I use this

```
[[ $(tr -d "\r\n" < file.name |wc -c) -eq 0 ]] && echo "File has no content"
```

but when we set that

```
echo "       " >file.name
```

then the follwing syntax will not print - File has no content

```
 [[ $(tr -d "\r\n" < file.name |wc -c) -eq 0 ]] && echo "File has no content"
```

so we are in trouble here

how to verify file is empty but can include spaces / TABs / blank 
or empty without anything

goal - verify file is empty but can include spaces / tab /blank lines , or empty without any spaces / blank lines / empty tab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With **`grep`**:

```
grep -q '[^[:space:]]' file.name || echo "file is empty or unreadable"
```

- `grep '[^[:space:]]' file.name` - will generate output only if any non-whitespace character `[^[:space:]]` found.
- `-q` suppresses the output to only retain the exit status that tells us if a non-spacing character was found or not.

Comment: If you tried to check for empty file content within an if condition, then you might got bash syntax error for using square brackets. see resolution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/534575/43233